# Tkz-graph and foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs, tkz-graph

I want to draw the following graph by using the usepackage  tkz-graph and the command foreach or by any other method: 
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-90]
\GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
\SetVertexNoLabel
\SetGraphUnit{1.5}
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.append style={fill=black, minimum size=7pt, inner sep=1pt}}
\Vertex{a}
\SOEA(a){b}
\NOEA(a){c}
\EA(b){d}
\EA(c){e}
\Edges(b,d,e,c,a,b,c,e,b)  
\Edges(e,a,d,c)  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Solution with vanilla `tikz`

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node style/.style = {fill = black, minimum size = 7pt, circle},
    edge style/.style = {black, thick},
  ]

  % base
  \foreach \i in {0,...,4} {
    \node[node style] (A\i) at ({2 * cos(72 * \i)}, {2 * sin(72 * \i)}) {};
  }

  % blocks
  \foreach \i [evaluate=\j as \j using {int(Mod(\i + 1, 5))}] in {0,...,4} {

    % nodes, each block has nodes (A, B, C, D, E)
    \node[node style] (C\i) at ($ (A\i)!2cm!-90:(A\j) $) {};
    \node[node style] (D\i) at ($ (A\j)!2cm!90:(A\i) $) {};
    \coordinate (T\i) at ($ (C\i)!0.5!(D\i) $);
    \node[node style] (E\i) at ($ (T\i)!1.5cm!-90:(D\i) $) {};

    % edges
    \draw[edge style] (A\i) -- (A\j) -- (C\i) -- (D\i) -- (A\i)
    -- (C\i) -- (E\i) -- (D\i) -- (A\j) (A\i) -- (E\i) -- (A\j);

  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Solution based on your graph and with `\foreach`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
house/.style={code={
\Vertex{a}
\SOEA(a){b}
\NOEA(a){c}
\EA(b){d}
\EA(c){e}
\Edges(b,d,e,c,a,b,c,e,b)  
\Edges(e,a,d,c)}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
\SetVertexNoLabel
\SetGraphUnit{1.5}
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.append style={fill=black, minimum size=7pt, inner sep=1pt}}
\foreach \X in {0,72,...,288}
{\path (\X-18:2.1) pic[rotate around={\X+180-18:(3,0)}] {house};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is tagged [tikz-graphs](/questions/tagged/tikz-graphs) here's a very similar solution to [caverac's approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/466299).

First we set up five [“color classes”](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#sec-19.7.1) and declare all nodes of each to be connected by using the [`clique` key](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#tikz/graphs/clique).

The inner most nodes will be placed via the [`circular placement` placement rule](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#tikz/graphs/circular:placement) and belong to two classes each.

In a `\foreach` loop these inner nodes will be used to place the other nodes via the `calc`'s library syntax. The “middle” nodes will be placed orthogonally to the inner ones but only 0.8× the distance between the inner ones. Then another third node will be placed orthogonally to the halfway point between the middle ones.

All these nodes will be declared to one of five sets so we don't have to place a single edge manually.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard, calc}
%\newcommand*\NextOf[2]{\pgfintmod{#1+1}{#2}}
\newcommand*\PrevOf[2]{\pgfintmod{#1-1}{#2}}
\begin{document}
\tikz\graph[
  no placement, empty nodes, nodes={circle, draw, fill, inner sep=+1.5pt},
  color class/.list={Set 0, Set ..., Set 4},
  clique/.list     ={Set 0, Set ..., Set 4}]{
  subgraph I_n[name=inner, V={0, ..., 4}, phase=0, counterclockwise=5,
    nodes={Set \tikzgraphnodename, Set \PrevOf{\tikzgraphnodename}{5}}],
  \foreach[evaluate={\j=int(mod(\i+1,5));}] \i in {0, ..., 4}{
    [nodes=Set \i]% or \j = \NextOf{\i}{5}
      middle \i a[at=($(inner \i)!.8!-90:(inner \j)$)],
      middle \i b[at=($(inner \j)!.8!+90:(inner \i)$)],
      outer \i c[at=($(middle \i a)!.5!(middle \i b)!1!-90:(middle \i b)$)]
  }
};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]